# How to system.in reopen in java?

Tags: java, system.in

When i use `scanner.close()`, `System.in` parameter is also closed.
I can understand a little this process with searching this site.
Some said if System.in is closed, it can't be reopened.
But they didn't have conviction for that.

---

So my question is this:
**How to `System.in` reopen? or is that impossible?**

---

for understanding my question, i put some example code here

```
public void scannerTest() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = input.nextInt();
    input.close();
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int j = input2.nextInt();
}
```

and result on console

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at repeat.Test.scannerTest(Test.java:55)
at repeat.Test.<init>(Test.java:19)
at repeat.Test.main(Test.java:11)
```

Comment: It's impossible. Once it's closed, it's closed.

Comment: Why are you asking this? Why would you want to close it?

Comment: You've reopened it in a new instance; simply use that instance: `int j = input2.nextInt();`

Comment: If System.in can't reopen, is there any reason using 'scanner.close()'?

Comment: @CynePhoba12 sorry. my code is some error. i edit it now. but still I found error

Comment: There is a reason, but only at the very end of the code... You only need **one** `Scanner`, though, to read many values.

Comment: @cricket_007 i know I can put the 'close' method at the very end of the code. But in view of resource, I think, that is useless, because program will end very soon. is that wrong?

Comment: @AndyTurner thanks for link. That is  i want to find.

Comment: It will be garbage collected, yes. The close method only exists because that class implements `Closeable` for other reasons. If the option to remove that method just because you used `System.in` existed, then someone would have done that. In other words, you can use `Scanner` for more than that.

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not native speaker so that I can't perfectly understand what you say.  is that correct that i understand?  _It is necessary because it is existed._

Comment: Nevermind... My point is that `System.in` is not the only variable for Scanner usage, and for those others, closing makes sense